# Index Subtree Of Items For A Specific Index

Tags: indexing

Is there a way to index a subtree of items for one specific index in code? I know there's the reindex tree button but that reindexes the subtree for all indexes the items are in. I don't see a good way to filter out indexes that I don't need to update right away in the code for that button.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this code snippet should do that:

```
ISearchIndex index = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex("sitecore_web_index");
Sitecore.Data.Database database = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase("web");
Sitecore.Data.Items.Item startingPoint= database.GetItem("/sitecore/content/home/someStartingItem");           
index.Refresh(new SitecoreIndexableItem(startingPoint));
```